# flow network, class and classroom matching

Tags: graphs, network-flow, bipartite-matching, minimum-cuts

Problem:

> given a set of classes and classrooms, then given a set M of pairs (a,b), which means it is valid assignment from class a to classroom b(ex:(c,2), (c,3), (d,2), means class c can be assigned to classroom 2 or 3, class d can only be assigned to classroom 2), each class can only be assign to a classroom at the same time.
>
> How do we find maximum assignment of the given set M at the same time?

My thought:

1. establish the source s connect to each class,each connect have capacity 1(which means we can only assign one class to one classroom)
2. connect each pair (a,b) in graph and each capacity is 1(establish valid connect)
3. connect all classroom to a sink each  capacity is 1(we can add each capacity 1 edge here then get maximum flow)

But it seems I will get the wrong answer when I push the flow.

How could I modify this graph to satisfy problem requirement?

Comment: `each class can only be assign to a classroom at the same time` and every classroom to no more than one class, probably. `wrong answer` isn't the most illumination problem description.